# unusual function definition - what is happening here

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I was going through the identity server 4 doc and I came across this piece of code.

```
private (TestUser user, string provider, string providerUserId, IEnumerable<Claim> claims) FindUserFromExternalProvider(AuthenticateResult result)
{
    var externalUser = result.Principal;

    // try to determine the unique id of the external user (issued by the provider)
    // the most common claim type for that are the sub claim and the NameIdentifier
    // depending on the external provider, some other claim type might be used
    var userIdClaim = externalUser.FindFirst(JwtClaimTypes.Subject) ??
                      externalUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) ??
                      throw new Exception("Unknown userid");

    // remove the user id claim so we don't include it as an extra claim if/when we provision the user
    var claims = externalUser.Claims.ToList();
    claims.Remove(userIdClaim);

    var provider = result.Properties.Items["scheme"];
    var providerUserId = userIdClaim.Value;

    // find external user
    var user = _users.FindByExternalProvider(provider, providerUserId);

    return (user, provider, providerUserId, claims);
}
```

and it is called like this.

```
var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
```

I dont quiet understand what is happening here. what sort of function definition usage is this?

Comment: [Value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)

Comment: i see what is happening here now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the returned data? It's a **value tuple** that is returned, see this [article](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/valuetuple) for a guide to Value Tuples. Value Tuples is a way to return multiple parameters without creating a custom class.

The method tries to lookup the user in the local database after the user has externally authenticated.